# MVC Controller parameters not required but optional

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Hi I'm using a HttpPost from a view to send some parameters to a controller, the db gets filtered according to those given parameters. BUT the parameters should be optional and if not given the controller just ignores them. But this seems to be impossible?

**VIEW**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Logbook")) {
 @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
       <div class="col-lg-3">
           <div class="panel panel-default">
               <div class="panel-heading">
                   <i class="fa fa-bell fa-fw"></i> Filter logbook
               </div>
               <div class="panel-body">
                   <div class="col-lg-5">
                        @Html.Label("Filter on room: ")
                        @Html.Label("Filter on date: ")
                   </div>
                   <div class="col-lg-6"> 
                        @Html.DropDownList("dropdownlist",Eindwerk.Controllers.RoomController.GetRooms(),new { @class = "btn btn-default-dropdown-toggle"})
                        @Html.TextBox("datepicker","", new { @class = "form-control" })
                   </div>
                <div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Filter logbook</button>
                @Html.ActionLink("Remove Filter", "Index","FilterClear",new { @class = "btn btn-outline btn-success btn-lg btn-block" })
           </div>
```

}

**CONTROLLER**

I thought it would be possible to just check if the parameter was null or not and change the function accordingly:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string dropdownlist, DateTime datepicker)
{
    if(dropdownlist != null && datepicker != null)
    return View(db.Logbook.Where(p => p.Room == dropdownlist && p.Time.Day == datepicker.Month).OrderByDescending(a => a.Id).ToList());

    if(dropdownlist != null && datepicker == null)
    return View(db.Logbook.Where(p => p.Room == dropdownlist).OrderByDescending(a => a.Id).ToList());

    if(dropdownlist == null && datepicker != null)
    return View(db.Logbook.Where(p => p.Time.Day == datepicker.Month).OrderByDescending(a => a.Id).ToList());

    else
    return View(db.Logbook.OrderByDescending(p => p.Id).ToList());

}
```

But I get an instant error that the parameters should be given, is there a possibility to set these parameters to optional?

Comment: Declare the parameter as nullable `DateTime? datepicker`

Comment: Indeed, so easy but didn't think of it. Thanks! Can't accept as answer though it's a comment...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare the parameter as nullable

```
public ActionResult Index(string dropdownlist, DateTime? datepicker)
```

Answer (score 0):

declare nullable parameters

```
public ActionResult Index(string? dropdownlist, DateTime? datepicker)
```

Comment: As Stephen Muecke already said: the solution was to set DateTime? datepicker as nullable. On string this doesn't have to cause string can be null. thanks anyway!

Comment: You can't have a string? parameter. String is already "nullable" by default.

Answer (score 0):

You can remedy this by making the parameter optional and assigning a default value of null:

```
public ActionResult Index(string dropdownlist, DateTime? datepicker = null){}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this it can be work

public ActionResult Index(string dropdownlist=null, DateTime datepicker=null)